# $fscanf function not working properly with CSV string input

Tags: csv, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to use the `$fscanf` function to read a CSV file in SystemVerilog.

This is the format of the CSV file:

```
REG_1,0xab4556
REG_2,0x124d
```

and so on...

I have to scan these values and assign them to variables Register Name and Value.
I am going to call these values later in the code, but for now this is the issue I am facing.

This is the function I am using to scan it:

```
while (!$feof(file)) begin
    $fscanf(file, "%s,%x", register_name, expected_value);

    $display("Register Name: %s, Value: %h", register_name, expected_value);
end
```

But, I am getting output like this

```
Register Name: REG_1,0xab4456, Value: 0x00000000
```

It is reading both of the columns of the CSV file into the first variable. How can I fix this?

Comment: `0x` is not a verilog syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your file contents do not work well with Verilog `$fscanf`.

The `%s` format essentially reads the entire line.  `%s` is a string format specification which incudes the comma.

If you can't change the contents of the file easily, you need to do a lot of work in Verilog.  For example, this code reads each line into 2 `string` variables:

```
module tb;

string register_name, line, expval;
int i;
initial begin
    int file;
    file = $fopen("file.csv", "r");
    while (!$feof(file)) begin
        $fscanf(file, "%s\n", line);
        register_name = "";
        for (i=0; i<line.len(); i++) begin
            if (line[i] == ",") begin
                break;
            end
            register_name = {register_name, line[i]};
        end
        expval = line.substr(i+1, line.len()-1);
        $display("Register Name: %s, Value: %s", register_name, expval);
    end
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
Register Name: REG_1, Value: 0xab4556
Register Name: REG_2, Value: 0x124d
```

If you want `Value` to be interpreted as a Verilog number instead of a string, you need to do more string parsing and conversion.